# How to get the first 3 values of an array using VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

How to get the  first 3 values out of an array?

Example :

```
a [0,0,2,2,3,0];

sel_x <= " ....";
sel_y <= "    ";
```

These are the signal declarations:

```
a : in std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);

sel_x : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
sel_y : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
```

Comment: Please add proper signal / variable declarations.

Comment: Please be aware, that also other users can edit your posts, e.g. to improve the text. If Javascript is enable, then a message appears on top of your post. If it is disabled, then please reload the page in your browser first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you mean with "first", but to assign the 3 leftmost entries if `a` to `sel_x`, you can do:

```
sel_x <= a(5 downto 3);
```

and in a more general way:

```
sel_x <= a(a'left downto a'left - 2);
```

Hope this can get you started, and maybe you should try using a simulator to validate the code, since the `a [0,0,2,2,3,0];` is not valid VHDL syntax.